# What emulator to use to test sw720dp-land layout

Tags: android, commonsware

I am running some sample code to test fragments:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/LargeScreen/EU4You

I am trying to test the results with the android emulator, but none of the emulators I select seem to work (they don't use the sw720dp-land layout). I do press Ctrl F11/F12 to rotate the screen to landscape.

Can someone tell me what settings to use when I create a new AVD in the Android Virtual Device Manager. Specifically, what 'Device' and 'Target'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you need an emulator with 720dp along its shortest axis.

So, for example, an emulator based on the `10.1" WXGA (Tablet)` stock device definition works, as that is an `-mdpi` emulator image with 1280x800 `px` resolution. `1dp` == `1px` at `-mdpi` density, and so that would qualify for `-sw720dp` resources.

In terms of target, `-sw720dp` was introduced in API Level 13 (Android 3.2), so you would need that or higher.

Comment: That makes sense and it is working for me now. I guess I was trying the wrong combinations. Thanks.